# how to get current active android app user email from firebase using firebaseAuth

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

My app have two user( buyer and seller).
I am tring to get current user email which is buyers but when i run the below code, it shows previously logged in user email which is the seller's one.

```
        String userID= FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getEmail();
```

How to write firebase code to get current active user email.

Comment: Why do you say "it shows previously logged in user email"? Have you successfully signed out?

Comment: A single `FirebaseApp` instance will only have at most one active user. Signing in or creating another user, automatically signs the previous user out. So it sounds like the seller was the last user to sign in.

Answer (score 0):

When you go to the Auth > Sign-In Methods page of your project in the Firebase console. do you have One account per email address on or off? If you allow multiple accounts per email address, you will get null for `FirebaseUser.getEmail()`

Answer (score 0):

Use this code snippet `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();` to `sign out` the current user properly, after successfully signed out you can repopulate your `user model` from Firebase Auth/login in `new user`. Hope your problem will be solved with this.